# Relation between semisimple Lie algebra completely reducibility and semisimple ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\frak g$ be a semi-simple finite dimensional Lie algebra over the complex numbers $\mathbb C$. Then every non irreducible representation of $\frak g$ is completely reducible.

**Q1:** Is category f.g. left $U(\mathfrak{g})$-Mod is equivalent to the category finite dimensional $\operatorname{Rep}(\mathfrak{g})$?

**Q2:** If every f.g $U(\mathfrak{g})$ module is completely reducible (in other words, they can be written as direct sums of simples) and above category equivalence holds, then from completely reducibility, I deduce for semi-simple Lie algebra, $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is semisimple as a ring. Hence, I would expect all $U(\mathfrak{g})$ modules to be projective and injective at the same time. Is this correct?

**Q3:** If Q1, Q2 are wrong, what is the relationship between semi-simple Lie algebras and semi-simple rings? (I would not expect for infinite dimensional representation, above categorical equivalence holds. The "semi-simple" ring should be interpreted as every f.g. module is decomposed into simple modules only.)

Comment: Then *every* finite-dimensional representation is completely reducible. So we don't need "non irreducible".

Comment: $U(\mathfrak g)$ is not finite dimensional !

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet Ah, my dumbness. I mistaken the product with lie bracket which is not associative. Thanks for the correction. So $U(g)$ is never finite dimensional unless $dim_C(g)=0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is semi-simpleness in representation same as semi-simpleness as ring sense? I mean semi simple here for f.g. objects only. The ring semi-simpleness demands much stronger statement for any modules, they decompose into simples.

Comment: @user45765 “Every fg module is semisimple” is equivalent to “every module is semisimple” for rings with identity.

Comment: @rschwieb Yes. I think I was confused when I was thinking about semisimpleness. f.g. module semisimple implies ring itself semisimple which implies all modules semisimple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give a definite answer :

**Q1** : No. For example, any simple modules can be expressed as some quotient of $U(\mathfrak g)$ (look for "Verma modules"), and there is so such module in $Rep(\mathfrak g)$.

**Q2** : No. For example, the natural sequence  $$ 0 \to M(-2) \to M(0) \to L(0) \to 0 $$  does not split (here $M(-2), M(0)$ are two Verma modules for $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and $L(0)$ is the trivial representation). Note that $M(0), M(-2)$ are infinite-dimensional.

**Q3** :  The only relation is that $Rep(\mathfrak g)$ is a semisimple category when $\mathfrak g$ is semisimple. So your last sentence is the correct interpretation.

Remark :  $U(\mathfrak g)$ is a rather complicated ring. For more information you can look at Dixmier's book on Universal Envelopping algebra. Also you can look at Humphrey's book about BGG category $\mathcal O$.